# Powerline Adapter Into prong Converter

Tags: receptacle, internet, adapter

I live in a pretty old house that has only 2 prong outlets on the floor where my router is. I have bad WifI in my room, two floors up so I bought [This Powerline Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00X3GX99C) However, the Adapter is 3 pronged, and the outlet has 2 prongs, so I need to use a prong adapter to plug it in. The one I tested may not be the best one, because it displays a bad connection light on the side using the adapter, but not in my room (which has 3 pronged outlets). Are there any prong adapters that I can use to make my connection stable that you would recommend?

Thank you.

Comment: Check  your two prong outlet box to see if it's grounded and then replace the outlet with a three prong.

Comment: If using a 3 prong receptacle on a 2 wire system it needs to be GFCI protected and a sticker stating GFCI protected no equipment ground.

Comment: Shoot a picture of your circuit breaker panel, and indicate which circuit (breaker) each of the two locations is on.

Comment: how old is your router? they have gotten a lot better in the past few years...